# How can i handle Apache Camel NoRouteToHostException exception?

Tags: web-services, exception, apache-camel

i want to treat the case when connection with Camel HTTP component cannot be established

example:

```
<from uri="timer:tm?period=2000"/>
<to uri="https://URI"/>
```

when there is no connection i get this exception:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
```

I want to handle this response and change it to an understandable message by the consumer. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exception using try..catch..finally.

http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html

Example in Spring DSL:

```
 <route id="send_request">
 <from uri="timer:tm?period=2000" />
 <doTry>
    <to uri="https://URI" />
    <doCatch>
        <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <log message="Some Message : ${exception.message}"
            loggingLevel="WARN" />
    </doCatch>
 </doTry>
```

Comment: Now i have a second  uri `https://URI2` i want to do a redirection to this uri if the connection with the first URi is failed. Where i should set the second URI ?

Comment: You can achieve this using Load Balancer. Check out this link:

http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html

<route id="test" errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
            <from uri="direct:xyz"/>
            <loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
                <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2"
                    roundRobin="true">
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                </failover>
                <to uri="http:// "/>
                <to uri="http:// "/>
            </loadBalance>
        </route>

Comment: yes it works `<loadBalance>
        <failover>
          <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
        </failover>
        <to uri="https://URi1"/>
        <to uri="URi2"/>
      </loadBalance><log message="${body}"/>` it works but i can't display the http response !

Comment: try this    <to uri="https://URI1"/><log message="${body}"/><to uri="https://URI2"/>

Comment: Please debug, check HTTP response code and check what is getting set in body. Response code is set in exchange header by the name 'CamelHttpResponseCode'

Comment: http response = 200 it works ! `<loadBalance>
        <failover roundRobin="false" maximumFailoverAttempts="2">
          <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
        </failover>
        <to uri="http://URi1"/>
        <to uri="URi2"/>
   </loadBalance>`
      <log message="Response: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} "/>

Comment: but when i turn to design mode the route changes to `<loadBalance>
        <failover roundRobin="false" maximumFailoverAttempts="2">
          <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
        </failover>
        <to uri="UR1"/>
        <to uri="http://URi2"/><log message="Response: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} "/>
       </loadBalance>` in this case response cannot be displayed or any endpoint can be used before </loadBalance> it should be after </loadBalance> to be displayed

Answer (score 2):

Camel provides a couple of very powerful error handling mechanisms with very useful redelivery and deadletter functionality. Those include:

- Error Handlers: https://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html
- Dead Letter Channels: https://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html
- Try, Catch & Finally: https://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html
- Exception Clause: https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

For your usecase, [Exception Clause](https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) is the best fit. Redelivery would help you to retry the HTTP call and avoid failure due to a temporary  downtime, e.g. a server restart:

```
<onException>
  <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
  <!-- retry 3 times with a delay of 10 seconds -->
  <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="3" logStackTrace="true" redeliveryDelay="10000" />
  <!-- only logs once redeliveries have failed -->
  <to uri="log:classToLog?level=ERROR"/>
</onException>
```